# Difference ok and end [Erlang]

Tags: erlang

What is the difference in ending a function with end and ok in Erlang?  I've been trying to grasp the meaning in the following code:

```
-module(esOne).
-export([start/1, func/1]).

start(Par) ->
    io:format("Client: I am ~p, spawned by the server: ~p~n",[self(),Par]),
    spawn(esOne, func, [self()]),
    Par ! {onPid, self()},
    serverEsOne ! {onName, self()},
    receiveMessage(),
    ok.

receiveMessage() ->
    receive
        {reply, N} ->
            io:format("Client: I received a message: ~p~n",[N])
    after
        5000->
            io:format("Client: I received no message, i quit~n",[])
    end.

func(Parent)->
    io:format("Child: I am ~p, spawned from ~p~n",[self(),Parent]).
```

This code works in conjunction with another .erl file that acts as server.  I managed to write this only through analyzing the given server file and copying it's behavior.  First I thought ok was used to end every function, but that is not the case as I can't end receiveMessage() with ok.  Then I thought I could maybe end every function with end, but start(Par) will give an error if I replace ok by end.  Not only that, but in the server file I see that ok and end are used within functions to end loops.  The way they're used look the same to me, yet they clearly fulfill a separate function as one cannot be replaced by another.  Some clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: I adjusted a few things in your example code for readability. When using `io:format` you want to use "~n" instead of "\n". Also, we usually use underscores for atoms `like_this_one` and camel case for `VariableNames`. This drastically improves readability and visual recognition -- to the point that source highlighting is usually a lot less important in Erlang.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two points to understand:

- Some code block types in Erlang are closed with an "end". So `if ... end`, `case ... end`, `receive ... [after N] ... end` and so on. It is certainly possible to use "end" as its own atom in place of OK, but that is not what is happening above.
- Every function in Erlang returns some value. If you aren't explicit about it, it returns the value of the last expression. The "=" operator isn't assignment to a variable like in other languages, it is assignment to a symbol as in math, meaning that reassigning is effectively a logical *assertion*. If the assertion fails, the process throws an exception (meaning it crashes, usually).

When you end something with "ok" or any other atom you are providing a *known* final value that will be returned. You don't have to do anything with it, but if you want the calling process to assert that the function completed or crash if anything unusual happened then you can:

```
do_stuff() ->
    ok = some_func().
```

instead of

```
do_stuff() ->
    some_func().
```

If some_func() may have had a side effect that can fail, it will usually return either `ok` or `{error, Reason}` (or something similar). By checking that the return was `ok` we prevent the calling process from continuing execution if something bad happened. That is central to the Erlang concept of "let it crash". The basic idea is that if you call a function that has a side-effect and it does anything unexpected at all, you should crash immediately, because proceeding with bad data is worse than not proceeding at all. The crash will be cleaned up by the supervisor, and the system will be restored to a *known state* instead of being in whatever random condition was left after the failure of the side-effect.

A variation on the bit above is to have the "ok" part appear in a tuple if the purpose of a function is to return a value. You can see this in any dict-type handling library, for example. The reason some data returning functions have a return type of `{ok, Value} | {error, Reason}` instead of just `Value | {error, Reason}` is to make pattern matching more natural.

Consider the following case clauses:

```
case dict:find(Key, Dict) of
    {ok, Value} ->
        Value;
    {error, Reason} ->
        log(error, Reason),
        error
end.
```

And:

```
case finder(Key, Struct) of
    Value ->
        Value;
    {error, Reason}
        log(error, Reason),
        error
end.
```

In the first example we match *the success condition first*. In the second version, though, this is impossible because the error clause could never match; any return at all would always be represented by `Value`. Oops.

Most of the time (but not quite always) functions that return a value *or* crash will return just the value. This is especially true of pure functions that carry no state but what you pass in and have no side effects (for example, `dict:fetch/2` gives the value directly, or crashes the calling process, giving you an easy choice which way you want to do things). Functions that return a value or signal an error usually wrap a valid response in `{ok, Value}` so it is easy to match.

Comment: In @zxq9 last example, you could revert the clauses: put `{error,Reason}` first, and `Value` second. It will work as long as the return Value cannot have the form `{error,Reason}`. So `{ok,Value}` is a better choice.

Comment: Yes and it allows you to easily write `{ok,Val} = finder(Key, Struct)` which crashes when nothing is found.

Comment: @rvirding ...which I find to be a good thing, but to a newcomer that might not sound like a good thing the way it is phrased. ;-)

Comment: @zxq9 true. :-) But when you get used to it: it is the standard way of crashing when a function does not return what you want, you match the return value against what you want. What is missing is being able to have guards in the match.

Comment: @rvirding I should start classifying situations where process crashes have saved the day, so I can start expressing why that is a good thing in a clear, concise way -- without having to take the audience through a whirlwind tour of the concurrent wonderland...

Comment: @zxq9 It took me a couple of readings to understand it, but I think I get it now.  Basically, end is used in conjunction with conditional statements, and ok signifies the end of the function, somewhat like 'return;' in Java.  While ok is not always necessary, it's a good way to indicate that the function ended properly.  Is that correct?  When I analyze the server file in this way, it's making sense to me now.  Thanks a lot for the in-depth explanation btw!

Comment: @Babyburger Basically, you got it. But remember, the `ok` is the actual return value, so its more like `return "ok";` in Java. Without that the value would be whatever the value returned by the last expression in the function was. Doing `ok = somefun()` in Erlang is like calling it with `if (somefun() != "ok") {throw new SomeException;}` in Java, and just calling `somefun(),` in Erlang is like just calling `somefun();` in Java, and letting the return value go in the trash. Anyway, you're on the right track. Toy with Erlang a bit and it will all suddenly seem so obvious. :-)

Comment: As @zxq9says the thing to remember is that a function **always** returns a value which is the value of the last things done in the body. Adding `ok` means that the last thing done is evaluating the atom `ok` which returns itself. The `end` is part of the `if/case/receive` syntax.